# Is there any way to get a list of all modules that were installed with pip install command?

Tags: python, pip

I am a high school student who programs in his free time, which includes on the school computer when I have the chance. However, every year when school lets out for the summer, they wipe the computer's memory. I have installed a lot of python modules over last year and saved all my programs to my home computer. However, I realized that when we get our laptops, I will have to go through the setup process for python again, and re install all the modules. Is there any way I can get a list of all python modules I have had to install so that I can write a script to install all the modules so I dont have to spend a few hours doing it all manually?

I have tried using

`> pip list`

and

```
python -c 'help("modules")'
```

both gave me a list of every module on the computer, most of which are there by default and do not need the install command to get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's great that you're looking for an efficient way to set up your Python environment with all the necessary modules after your school computer memory gets wiped. To get a list of only the modules you've installed, you can use the [`pip freeze`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_freeze/) command. This will give you a list of all installed packages along with their versions. You can then save this list to a [`requirements.txt`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/requirements-file-format/) text file for reference.

Here's how you can do it:

1. Open the command prompt or terminal on your school computer.
2. Run the following command to generate a list of installed packages and their versions:

   ```
   pip freeze > requirements.txt
   ```
3. This will create a file named `requirements.txt` in your current directory with the list of packages.
4. Copy the `requirements.txt` file to your home computer.
5. When you need to set up your Python environment again, you can use the following command to install all the modules listed in the `requirements.txt` file:

   ```
   pip install -r requirements.txt
   ```

This will save you from manually installing each module again. Just remember to update the `requirements.txt` file whenever you install new modules in the future.

***References***:

- [`requirements.txt`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/requirements-file-format/)
- [`pip freeze`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_freeze/)

Comment: You basically covered every point I would have here, except the fact that this is now considered outdated; [pyproject.toml](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/#creating-pyproject-toml) is the way forward it seems

Comment: Also [`pipreqs`](https://pypi.org/project/pipreqs/) for generating the imports without pinning _everything_

Comment: @roganjosh `pyproject.toml` can not help in this case. `pip freeze > requirements.txt` is probably more helpful. [About `requirements.txt`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/requirements-file-format/). [About `pip freeze`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_freeze/).

Comment: @roganjosh This was an interesting point. I had not read this before, but I always create an environment, I try to keep all the names and versions of the packages. Ah, one point, you can save all these things by executing (.exe)  the activity folder.  and then install it in the right place

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with `.exe`. You should make packages from the start, and this is the settled-upon 102930303'rd way of doing that

Comment: `pip freeze > requirements.txt` was never a great idea, use [`pipreqs`](https://pypi.org/project/pipreqs/) for that. But `requirements.txt` will be dead soon (so sayeth the tea leaves)

Comment: Thank you! I got my computer and was able to set everything up manually before you said this, however I will try it when I help friend get python.